# Searching for a string within a string

Tags: php, regex

I am beginner php developer. I need found values in my string (post code).

I make this code:

```
private function findPostCode(string $string): array|null
    {
        preg_match("(\b\d{2}\s*-\d{3}\b)", $string, $matches);
        if($matches){
            return $matches;
        }
        if(!$matches){
            preg_match("(\b\d{2}\s*\d{3}\b)", $string, $matches);
            return $matches;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When i have string: '99888 city street' or '99-888 city street' - it's work fine.
I have array with my results.

Problem is when i have more post code: '99888 12-230 city street 98-234'.
I have always one results.

How can i repair it?

Please help me

Comment: Side notes: 1) you don't need `if(!$matches){`. You already exited the function should that happen. 2) You can combine both expressions in one if you make the `-` optional with `?`, as in `-?`.

Comment: What's the output you expect though?

Comment: Adding to @ÁlvaroGonzález' side notes:  1b) testing the exact opposite of the previous condition is also superfluous nonsense to begin with, regardless of the specific return situation here - `else` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `preg_match()` function find only first matches.

You need to use `preg_match_all()` function for find all possible matches.

Your solution code looks like :

```
private function findPostCode(string $string): array|null
{
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("(\b\d{2}\s*-\d{3}\b|\b\d{2}\s*\d{3}\b)", $string, $matches);
    if(count($matches[0]) > 0){
        return $matches[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Cheers! If it helps you to solve your problem then you can upvote and tick as right answer for others too...